# Can I get a function info(return/parameter type) in another function with C++?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, types

See my demo code below:

```
string foo(double a, double b) {
  //...
}

void goo(foo) {
  // ... do something base on string/double/double of foo
}
```

I want do something in `goo` base on the return/parameter type of `foo`, how can I make with C++?

One possible way is to bind `foo` and `goo` in a template class object.

In my real case, `foo` and `goo` are not determined at the same time which means you can't bind them together.

Comment: The return type must be `string` because of the typedef `func`. Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @JosephMansfield foo can be any return/parameter type, but only 2 input parameters

Comment: *"In my real case, foo and goo are not determined at the same time"*, does that mean `foo` could change after you have complied `goo`? There is `decltype`, but it would require `foo`'s definition to be visible when `goo` gets complied.

Comment: Do you want that `goo` can take any function pointer that take exactly 2 parameters ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you pass `foo` by pointer, you can use templates:

```
template<typename R>
void bar(R (*func)(double, double))
{
    // Do something with func
    // example:
    R variable = func(3.14, 42);
    std::cout << variable;
}
```

Use:

```
bar(foo);
// or
bar(&foo);
```

It is also possible to do some meta-programming based on `R`. Note that you can also use templates for the function parameters:

```
template<typename R, typename P1, typename P2>
void bar(R (*func)(P1, P2))
{
    // ...
}
```